# after cleaning some code in my home.vue file in my vue js project i keep seeing these error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, web-deployment

Failed to compile.

./src/views/Home.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\OSOKA\Desktop\VUE\vue-shop\src\views\Home.vue
2:21  warning  Delete `⏎···⏎··`                                             prettier/prettier
14:5   error    The "HelloWorld" component has been registered but not used  vue/no-unused-components

✖ 2 problems (1 error, 1 warning)
0 errors and 1 warning potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the HelloWorld component but aren't using it in your template code.

Comment: Delete the HelloWorld import statement and then delete the component. If you aren't using the component in the template, then why would you import it? Also, next time you post a question, you should post some code too so we can see what's going on. In this case it was somewhat easy since the error literally tells you what's wrong, but code is always helpful. Help us help you.